# Selecting row where Value = Parameter or Value is NULL AND Parameter is not in Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select a row from a table with the logic that if a value in a field matches a parameter or the field is null and no record matches the parameter, return that row.  This is a super simple example:

Sample Table:

```
ID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
===|========|========|===========
1  | NULL   | Hello  | World
2  | Hello  | NULL   | World
3  | NULL   | Hello  | Everybody
```

Sample query that doesn't quite work:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (Value1 IS NULL OR Value1 = 'Hello')
AND     (Value3 IS NULL OR Value3 = 'World')
```

Results that I get with above query:

```
ID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
===|========|========|========
1  | NULL   | Hello  | World
2  | Hello  | NULL   | World
```

My Desired Results:

```
ID | Value1 | Value2 | Value3
===|========|========|========
2  | Hello  | NULL   | World
```

Unfortunately, due to the complexity of the table and the select, I can't do similar to the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   ((Value1 IS NULL
          AND NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Value1 = 'Hello')
        OR      Value1 = 'Hello'))
AND     (Value3 IS NULL OR Value3 = 'World')
```

Comment: When you say "return that row", what is "that" row? Why is ID 2 returned? If no record matches the parameter, do you want to return the first row where the field is null?

Comment: Your expected results / query do not match your stated goal. You said "parameter" (singular) but then you describe a situation where you are looking for 2 distinct values. So - try again. And you may find that you must use 2 separate queries because you cannot, within a single select statement, "know" if there are no rows that match some set of criteria to determine if you need to use the "fallback" non-matching criteria(which doesn't make sense as Andrew indicated). Help yourself and use a larger set of test data - too limited as is.